# Tomcat 9.x + weld - using an injection point for Constructor

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jboss-weld

I use Tomcat 9.x and Weld 3.x. The injection points for the field and for the setter work fine.

```
  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>8.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
      <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.SP1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--<dependency>-->
      <!--<groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>-->
      <!--<artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>-->
      <!--<version>2.4.8.Final</version>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
<dependency>
         <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
         <artifactId>weld-servlet-shaded</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.5.Final</version>
       </dependency>

  </dependencies>
```

This Managed bean

```
@RequestScoped
public class Student {

    private String name;

    public Student() {
        this.name = "Ivan";
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

this servlet

```
@WebServlet("/index.html")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Inject
    Student student;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

        student.setName("Alex");

        writer.println("<h2>");
        writer.println("Hello " + this.student.getName() + " !");
        writer.println("</h2>");
        writer.println("</br>" + "</br>");
    }
}
```

this.beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
        xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
        bean-discovery-mode="annotated">
</beans>
```

I tried to find the library Weld, but generally for servlets I found 2 that work.
But the injection point for the Constructor doesn't work.
can someone explain what the problem is?
Who has any ideas?

Here's the use of the consturtor at the injection point

```
@WebServlet( "/index.html" )
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public static String URI = "/beanExample.jsp";


    Student student;

    @Inject
    public HelloServlet() {
        this.student = student;
    }


    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        setCharacter(request, response);

        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

      student.setName("Alex");
        writer.println("<h2>");
        writer.println("Hello " + this.student.getName() + " !");
        writer.println("</h2>");
        writer.println("</br>" + "</br>");

    }
```

The **injection point** is the point marked by the annotation @**Injection point.**
At this point, the CDI container creates the object and manages its lifecycle.

Comment: What do you mean by `the injection point for the Constructor doesn't work`? What is the actual problem and the error you are seeing? Does injection work for you?

Comment: I write additionally above. And this last example is not work.